# Unable to restrict loops to 21 lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I am trying to loop over a list. Each row contains three numbers. The list can be as long as it can be but I just want to check the first 21 rows. I've tried using islice but I cannot seem to get it right.

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv

f = open(filename)

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    fields = line.split(" ")

    x = int(fields[0])
    y = int(fields[1])
    z = int(fields[2])

    for n in range(1, z):
        if n % x == 0 and n % y == 0:
            print "FB",
        elif n % x == 0:
            print "F",
        elif n % y == 0:
            print "B",
        else:
            print n,

    print line

    if not line:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure why you can't get `islice` to work.  A working example using it is:

```
import itertools

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in itertools.islice(f, 21):
        fields = line.split(" ")
        # Rest of your code here...
```

This is probably the easiest solution as you don't need to introduce additional complexity into your code to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this obvious?

```
...

lineNumber=1

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    fields = line.split(" ")

    ...

    lineNumber = lineNumber +1
    if lineNumber > 21:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use fact, that zip takes elements until one of iterables runs out of them:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line, i in zip(f, range(21)):
        print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to also track line number but it starts from 0 so first line is index `0`

```
f = open(filename)

for i, line in enumerate(f):
    fields = line.split(" ")

    x = int(fields[0])
    y = int(fields[1])
    z = int(fields[2])

    for n in range(1, z):
        if n % x == 0 and n % y == 0:
            print "FB",
        elif n % x == 0:
            print "F",
        elif n % y == 0:
            print "B",
        else:
            print n,

    print line

    if not line or i == 20:
        break
```

Break if not line or if line number equals `20`, 21st line

Comment: that's why `i < 21` looks better ;) and you should move the check to the start of the loop...

Comment: you should rather check `if not i <21` or `if i >= 21` imho

Comment: Note that `enumerate()` can take an optional second arg to specify the number to start counting from.